# iPhone App link to iStore for commission

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is it possible to link from an iPhone application to the iStore so a user can (a) play a sample of music and then navigate to that track in order to buy it?
In a bit more detail: the application lists a number of tracks for a particular artist (a recommendation by the app based on user criteria). The user scrolls down the list and finds a track that they are interested in. They play the 30 second sample (as you would in the iStore) and then, if they like it, they press on a link that takes them to the iStore where they can purchase the track. If they buy the track, then the application gets 5% of the money paid for the track.
I have looked through the web and found a number of suggestions but nothing seems to fit the specification above. 
I would be very grateful if anyone is able to tell me whether this is possible and some clues as to how it would be done.
Thanks,
Simon...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to become an iTune Affiliate

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/

-t